# Getting data from function that takes time to calculate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, asynchronous, delay

I develop my own react web service that renders diagrams to the screen with canvas API.
The problem is that at some point of time when a user clicks a calculate button a canvas() function is called. Depending on its arguments it can really take time to return the result (there are a lot of loops), so even console in the browser freezes and logs the result after some time (it can be 1-5 secs or even a minute).
So I wonder what is really happening with my code.
It's too robust to provide it here, but its piece I'm interested in looks like this:

1. User clicks the button and data (user's input) is passed to canvas function.
2. Canvas function is invoked and it returns the result - a javaScript object. Before return statement I console.log the result.
3. After it I call setState method and render result to the screen. At this point I pass resulting JS object from (2) to my state.

I know that JavaScript "reads" code from top to bottom, but before I see console.log from (2), the result is already rendered to the screen. So this means that the result is already returned and the state is set, otherwise I wouldn't see it's rendered. But the console.log that is above the return statement is shown after some time.
So the question is how should I deal with it? I tested it on different fast computers and the result is always the same. Is it just a freeze of the browser (chrome, safari) and it works like a synchronous function or should I use await or something to provide time to canvas function to finish before the content is rendered. This is important because I care of this result and I want to be sure that setState is called with a proper data.

Comment: Execute the long calculation in a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and have the answer passed directly back to the main execution context.  Workers are JS' way to do multithreading.  It's what I ended up doing for a ray tracer that I wrote that would calculate the raycasted scene in a worker and then hand back the finished image to the main context to put into a canvas.  We can't give you exact instructions because you haven't provided an [mre].

Comment: Thank you, zero298! I'll try this. But can you please answer how does it work right now? I mean does the setState wait for canvas() to return the result or how can I see the result on the screen without canvas() finished (before it logs the result from inside)